# Passing more than one command Arguments in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, commandargument

I have a TemplateField column in a gridview with a image button inside of it.
i need to use two command arguments within single image button.
here is my code

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAvaililabitly" runat="server" 
                          ImageUrl="~/CMS/images/available_icon.png"
                          Width="12px" Height="12px" CommandName="availability" 
                          ToolTip="Rooms Availability"
                          CommandArgument='<%#Eval("HotelID")%>'/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

please help

Comment: Why? Do you have a key for the table that you list here? Then use that. However,you can use a separator(e.g. comma) and split it on serverside.

Comment: I formatted your markup to make it neat and tidy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multiple argument through CommandArgument of Button in Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389258/passing-multiple-argument-through-commandargument-of-button-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 5):

You can send comma separated string and collect value on server side

```
CommandArgument= '<%# String.Format("{0} , {1}", Eval("Name1"), Eval("Name2")) %>'
```

Comment: i got error after applying that "Server Tag not well formed "
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CMS/images/edit_icon.png"
                                                  Width="12px" Height="12px" CommandName="edit" ToolTip="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("HotelID")%>','<%#Eval("IsSpanish")%>' />

Comment: Try this, '<%#Eval("HotelID")%>,<%#Eval("SccondColumn")%>'

Comment: this shows another error "Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line "